# SELECT * FROM USERS where userid = (null or '') is this t sql query valid or not?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users
 WHERE userid = (null OR '')
```

Is this **TSql** query `userid = (null OR '')` *valid* or not?

Comment: This query is not valid in SQL Server.  If you attempt to run it, you will get a syntax error.  That is a hint.

Comment: _is this t sql query valid or not?.._ Have you tried to run it at all?

Comment: Typically if you want to give a column a list of allowable values, you don't use = you use IN as in `userid IN (value1, value2)`, though I am not sure this would work with NULL being one of those values.

Comment: @bjk116: it's easy to test: `select * from (values (null)) v(x) where x in (null)` returns nothing because `null = null` is not true.

Comment: @– bjk116  yes , one of my comparison is with NULL .

Comment: In SQL you can't compare with NULL. Something either IS NULL or it IS NOT NULL.

Comment: `userid is null or userid = ''`

Comment: Yea I figured it would have to be `userId IS NULL or userId IN (value1, value2, ...)`

Comment: @– Dmitry Bychenko   --  Thanks , yes this will work I just wanted to know the other way. Now As per every ones comment , I guess the only other way is IN operator , but not sure with NULL. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @– bjk116   --  thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison

```
 userid = (null OR '')
```

is **invalid**. First, the very syntax is wrong:

```
 field = (value1 OR value2)
```

should be put either as

```
(field = value1) OR (field = value2)
```

or as

```
 field IN (value1, value2)
```

Second, `null` is a *special value*, which stands for *unknown*, *doesn't matter*, *unapplicable* etc. and that's why `null = null` is equal not to `True`, but to `null` (does *unknown* equal to *unknown*? It's *unknown*.) There are some exceptions when `null = null` is `True` (e.g. `GroupBy`). However, in order to be on the *safe side* do not put `field = null` or `field in (..., null, ...)`, but `field is null`.
In your case

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users
 WHERE (userid is null) 
    OR (userid = '')
```